# Multiple data questionaire nominal value - how to aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

I have data in time slots.

```
ds = [ds01, ds02, ds03, ds04, ...]
```

for the results in the loop using:

```
nhelp = []
for d in ds:
    nhelp.append(d.groupby(list(d)[1]).size().sum)  #single column
nhelp
```

e.g. for the favourite colour (which datas are representated as 1 2 3 ... in the questionaire)
here i do get:

```
[<bound method Series.sum of color
1.0    215
2.0    202
3.0    215
4.0    178
dtype: int64>, <bound method Series.sum of color
1.0    252
2.0    244
3.0    241
4.0    133
dtype: int64>, <bound method Series.sum of color
........ 
dtype: int64>]
```

now I want to sum up the colors for all time periods and show the results in a single diagram. (Here I tried pivot, crosstable, loops, - converting list to array or/and to dataframe - sumation and plot failed, Its also not possible to iterate this variable, but I can access the value e.g. nhelp[1][1])

Comment: I did not really understand what you are asking, but you should try to replace `nhelp.append(d.groupby(list(d)[1]).size().sum)` with `nhelp.append(d.groupby(list(d)[1]).size().sum())`

Comment: @Scotty1 - using your suggestion I do get just a single number per timeslot and not a table with the colors. I tried my best to state my issue ... .

Comment: Yes, the sum of values is **always** a single number (per row or column). What result do you want? `cumsum`? Could you please add a data sample?

Comment: @Scotty1 My column for the color contains [1,3,4,2,6,4,6,3, ...] - each number representing a color. what I want to have is not the sum of all numers - I need the counts of color 1, color 2 and so forth. - and these for all lists ds01, ds02 . I now also tried to goup the gouped data - 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need join all data by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and then sum by `Index`:

```
nhelp = []
for d in ds:
    nhelp.append(d.groupby(list(d)[1]).size())

out = pd.concat(nhelp).sum(level=0)
```

Or list comprehension:

```
nhelp = [d.groupby(list(d)[1]).size() for d in ds]
out = pd.concat(nhelp).sum(level=0)
```

Comment: here i do get a : FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  return self._engine.get_loc(key);